Parallelization of stacked learner tuning using the ti() function from the mlr3 package
I am trying to integrate parallel computing into the stacked learner tuning using the ti() function from the mlr3tuning package. I have included two levels: level 0 allows tuning of 9 learners, and level 1 calculates the average of the predictions from the 9 learners. I included 9 learners: classif.gausspr, classif.glmnet, classif.rpart, classif.kknn, classif.svm, classif.gbm, classif.xgboost, classif.ranger, classif.nnet. In the mlr3 book, the example given to illustrate parallel tuning does not apply to stacked learners. Therefore, I am not sure if I am doing things correctly, especially since my script takes a long time to run (currently, I cannot get the results from my script). I have included the main code of my script below.
In case my script is incorrect, I was wondering if this solution would be correct: I was thinking of doing parallel computing as follows:
Step 1: Create a list of learners "learner_list"
Step 2: Perform parallel computing on each learner like this:
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(4, outfile = “Output.txt")
    doSNOW::registerDoSNOW(cl)

tuner_output_list <- foreach::foreach(learner_ID = 1:9, .errorhandling = "pass") %dopar% {

## Run the function "ti() " for each learner
run_tuner  <- mlr3tuning::ti(tuner = tuner, 
                                    learner = learner_list[[learner_ID]],
                                    resampling = resampling,
                                    measure = measure,
                                    terminator = terminator)

}

parallel::stopCluster(cl)

Step 3: Retrieve the results of the tuning from the step 2
Step 4: Apply the function mlr_learners_classif.avg using the tuning results from the step 2 (but I am not quite sure how to do this at the moment).
Code for stacked learner tuning
inner_resampling <- mlr3::rsmp ("cv", folds = 2)

performance_measures <- c(mlr3::msr("classif.sensitivity"), mlr3::msr("classif.specificity"), 
                           mlr3::msr("classif.acc"), mlr3::msr("classif.auc"))

terminator <- mlr3tuning::trm("evals", n_evals = 100)

tuner <- mlr3tuning:::tnr("mbo")



    ## Create tuning instance
      instance <- mlr3tuning::ti(task = task, 
                                               learner = lrn_graph_1, 
                                               resampling = inner_resampling,
                                               measures = performance_measures,
                                               terminator = terminator)
    
    ## Run the tuning process  
      tuner$optimize(create_tuning_instance)


The parallelization of tuning will work regardless of the underlying learner, i.e. it should work just fine for stacked learners. Do you have reason to believe that it doesn't work?

@Lars: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm not sure I understand how the parallelization of tuning can work because I'm using a multi-objective tuning approach. The book states: 'As multi-objective tuning requires manual intervention to select a configuration, it is currently not possible to use auto_tuner().' Also, I believe that I have no other choice but to proceed step by step, as suggested in my post.

That's correct, but it's because of multi-objective optimization and not because of stacking.
